# How to access a Jackrabbit Oak repository via WebDAV?

Tags: webdav, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

When I start a Jackrabbit 2 repository, I can just connect to it via WebDAV easily via http://localhost:8080/repository/default

**This does not work with Oak though.**

Unfortunately it is not well documents and all I could find, which is Oak & WebDAV-related, were these tickets in Jira

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-4?focusedCommentId=13236811&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13236811
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OAK-104

and the mailing list post

- http://jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/Exception-while-tryng-to-connect-to-Oak-via-WebDav-td4661166.html#a4661173,

which did not give me any useful hint.

So my questions are actually two questions:

**1) How to connect to an Oak repository via WebDAV which runs standalone?**

**2) How to connect to an Oak repository via WebDAV which is created/embedded in an application? How to expose the port and how to enable WebDAV?**

Are there any code samples anywhere? The documentation is not really helpful enough.

I checked the Oak repository and found the oak-examples with a standalone application and a README at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/oak/trunk/oak-examples/standalone/README.md.

It says:

> Once done you can run the application by executing
>
> ```
> $ java -jar target/oak-standalone-*.jar
>  This would start an Oak based repository which uses filesystem storage. All  the content would be by default stored under `oak`
> ```
>
> folder. The server would listen at port 8080 and support remote access
>   via DavEx (at `/server`)  and WebDAV (at `/repository`).

However, this does not work. When trying to connect to http://localhost:8080/repository with my WebDav client or in the browser, I get a `404 not found` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing the workspace name (`default`) in the URL.

Following the instructions on https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/oak/trunk/oak-examples/standalone/README.md and then starting the repository via

```
java -jar target/oak-standalone-*.jar
```

I can access it via WebDav at http://localhost:8080/repository/default/. I missed to put the `/default` in the URL.